# How to to specify a word plus a date in a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to specify a word plus a date in a cell.

```vb
Sub CurrentTestCell()
    With Range("i2")
    .Value = ("Test") And Date
    .NumberFormat = "mmmm yyyy"
  End With
End Sub
```

The code without `("Test)" And` shows the current date.

Cell i2 should show "Test December 2021".

Error:

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Comment: Can try `.Value = Date` and then `.NumberFormat = """Test"" mmmm yyyy"` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date format will not work on text data. You need format function for dates. Try-

```
Sub CurrentTestCell()
    With Range("I2")
    .Value = "Test " & Format(Date, "mmmm yyyy")
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes this shows the date but should be a word and then the date for example "This is a word December 2021".

Comment: @OnlyProblems Try edited answer.